# Show desktop button for GNOME 3

Tags: gnome3, desktop

https://www.gnome.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/activities-overview-940x529.png

On GNOME 3, RHEL 7, how can I create a button that can be very easily reached with the mouse (only 1 click if anything is open), that can bring all the open windows to the taskbar? Like a "show desktop" icon on GNOME 2 or in Windows.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/64/show-desktop-button/

Answer (score 2):

You can create an application launcher with the contents like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Show-Desktop
Exec=wmctrl -k on
```

Then save it naming like `show-desktop.desktop` and give it execution permission (`chmod +x`).

*Now you can add it to your panel or task-bar whatever and clinking on it will show you desktop as expected.*

**Note**: It requires `wmctrl` installed on your system.

```
NAME
       wmctrl - interact with a EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager.
```

```
-k  ( on  |  off  )
              Turn on or off the window manager's "show the desktop" mode (if the window manager implements this fea‐
              ture).
```

Comment: Great answer! Works in Xfce as well. But in my opinion there are two cons with this solution: 1) If you have several workspaces, all windows on all workspaces are minimized. I guess the wanted behaviour would be to affect only the active workspace. 2) Is there a way to make it a toggle button, so that clicking it again will reset all windows as they were before (as in MS Windows 8)?