# How do I "show desktop" in Fedora 38 with mouse?

Tags: fedora, gnome, mouse, desktop

I know I could set up shortcut key for "show desktop", but I need to do it with a mouse. What do I click to show the desktop?

Os is default Fedora 38 with Gnome desktop.

I asked ChatGPT and googled, all answers seem to relate to shortcut keys.

Comment: It's weird. I voted to close the question 'cause there's a question on SE which is talking about the same exact issue and also it has a solution, yet my comment has been deleted. Abso-f-lutely fantastic moderation is going on here.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov you voted to close a question asking for a solution using _the mouse_ as duplicate of one discussing _command line_ solutions instead. So the other question is not about the "same exact issue". So yes, the mod who deleted your comment, not I by the way, did an absolutely fantastic job.

Comment: For a mouse command you create an application shortcut and you're done. Have a good day, @terdon.

Comment: Excellent, there's an answer, @ArtemS.Tashkinov, please post it. But it isn't mentioned anywhere on the suggested dupe and requires non-trivial technical knowledge hence, a new question is merited.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used Gnome, but it did have the option of "hot corners", i.e., you move the mouse to one of the screen corners, and get the "activities" menu, which I think is what you mean when you say "Desktop" (the Windows 95 style "Desktop with shortcuts" doesn't exist in Gnome, as far as I know).

If you move your mouse to the top left corner of your screen and nothing happens, the feature might be disabled.

You'll need to look in the settings, look for "Multitasking" (?) and check the "hot corners" switch.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could install and use any available "Show Desktop" extension for Gnome.
2. Dash to Panel has the hide windows button on the right which does that as well: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/
3. You could create a shortcut as shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258495